# NodeJS/Express to serve a React App returning Content Security Policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I build the NodeJS/Express application below to serve my React app.
The 'build' path is the result of `npm run build` from my React app.

```
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require('helmet');           
const compression = require('compression'); // compression file
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html'));
});

app.listen(4000);
```

The index.html of my React app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="my app" />
        <meta name="description" content="My Website" />
        <meta name="author" content="FName Name" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
        />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
        <!-- css added by Mohammed :: starts -->

        <!-- favicon icon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/favicon.ico" />

        <!-- inject css start -->

        <!--== bootstrap -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />

        <!--== animate -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/animate.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== fontawesome -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/fontawesome-all.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== line-awesome -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/line-awesome.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== magnific-popup -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== owl-carousel -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== base -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/base.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== shortcodes -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/shortcodes.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== default-theme -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/style.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== responsive -->
        <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/responsive.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />

        <!--== color-customizer -->
        <!--<link href="/#" data-style="styles" rel="stylesheet" />-->
        <!-- <link
            href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/color-customize/color-customizer.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        /> -->
        <!-- css added by Mohammed :: ends -->
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->

      <!-- inject js start -->

        <!--== jquery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!--== popper -->
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>

        <!--== bootstrap -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--== appear -->
        <script src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>

        <!--== modernizr -->
        <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

        <!--== easing -->
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

        <!--== menu -->
        <script src="js/menu/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>

        <!--== owl-carousel -->
        <script src="js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

        <!--== magnific-popup -->
        <script src="js/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

        <!--== counter -->
        <script src="js/counter/counter.js"></script>

        <!--== countdown -->
        <script src="js/countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

        <!--== canvas -->
        <script src="js/canvas.js"></script>

        <!--== confetti -->
        <script src="js/confetti.js"></script>

        <!--== step animation -->
        <script src="js/snap.svg.js"></script>
        <script src="js/step.js"></script>

        <!--== contact-form -->
        <script src="js/contact-form/contact-form.js"></script>

        <!--== wow -->
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

        <!--== color-customize -->
        <!-- <script src="js/color-customize/color-customizer.js"></script> -->

        <!--== theme-script -->
        <script src="js/theme-script.js"></script>

        <!-- inject js end -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The Fact app is running just fine in localhost test. However, when I open it by the NodeJS server that I build, the page does not open and the browser show the error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)
```

Comment: You haven't *configured* Helmet - the default rules from version 4 up are quite strict.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you please explain it? I'm new with NodeJS, I'm not sure what it means

Comment: See [the package docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) for how to configure it - they also link to the MDN pages on the CSP if you're unfamiliar with that.

Comment: I added to helmet ```contentSecurityPolicy: false``` and still getting the same error

Comment: Yes, I needed to add the directives ```"script-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "myirent.com"],```. Thank you. If you want to answer the post, I can accept it.

Comment: That's covered in the proposed duplicate, you should see an option to accept that suggestion somewhere on the page.